# Eigenvalue function of the representation variety of free abelian group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices, abelian-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $\rho:\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow \SL(n,\mathbb C)$ be a representation of a finitely generated free abelian group, by simultaneously triangularization, we can assume that $\rho$ takes image in the upper triangular matrices, with diagonal entries the set of **"eigenvalues"**
$$E(\rho):=\{\chi_1,\cdots,\chi_n\},\quad \chi_i:\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow \mathbb C^\times$$
consisting of 1-dimensional characters.

Intuitively the set $E(\rho)$ is well-defined (irrelevant of the triangularization) and the set $E(\rho)$ varies continuously with respect to $\rho$ in the representation variety $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z^n,\SL(n,\mathbb C))$. Is it in fact true?

Comment: Don't both of these follow from the fact that the character of the representation determines $E(\rho)$ and varies continuously?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you please elaborate a little bit or recommend a relevant reference? Thanks!

Comment: If $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix then the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is a fixed polynomial function of the traces $\text{tr}(M^k), 1 \le k \le n$, and the eigenvalues vary continuously as the characteristic polynomial varies. So as a representation varies continuously, so does its character, hence so do the characteristic polynomials of every element, hence so do their eigenvalues.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think the question demands more, it's true that the eigenvalues for $\rho(g_1)$ are continuous for a single generator $g_1\in\mathbb Z^n$, but it seems tricky for me to group the eigenvalues of $\rho(g_1),\cdots,\rho(g_n)$ together and describe them as characters of $\mathbb Z^n$, then investigate the well-definedness and continuity of these $n$ characters. Or maybe there are some trick in it but I don't know yet.

Comment: If you believe that the eigenvalues for $\rho(g_i)$ vary continuously for each $g_i$ individually then they vary continuously for the tuple $\rho(g_1), \dots \rho(g_n)$ and that determines the whole character.